# Android nor resource identifier found

Tags: android, android-drawable, android-6.0-marshmallow, fingerprint

Hi i am trying to use a Vector drawable to draw a fingerprint icon from the example xml from android dev website and i get an errior saying it cant find any of the attributes set on this drawable.

below is the code:

```
<vector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        android:width="40.0dp"
        android:height="40.0dp"
        android:viewportWidth="40.0"
        android:viewportHeight="40.0">
    <path
        android:pathData="M20.0,20.0m-20.0,0.0a20.0,20.0 0.0,1.0 1.0,40.0 0.0a20.0,20.0 0.0,1.0 1.0,-40.0 0.0"
        android:fillColor="#009688"/>
    <path
        android:pathData="M11.2,21.41l1.63,-1.619999 4.17,4.169998 10.59,-10.589999 1.619999,1.63 -12.209999,12.209999z"
        android:fillColor="#FFFFFF"/>
</vector>
```

My Min and compiledSdk is set to 19 :

errors i get when i try to do a clean/rebuild:

```
Error:(17) No resource identifier found for attribute 'viewportWidth' in package 'android'
Error:(17) No resource identifier found for attribute 'viewportHeight' in package 'android'
Error:(22) No resource identifier found for attribute 'pathData' in package 'android'
Error:(22) No resource identifier found for attribute 'fillColor' in package 'android'
Error:(25) No resource identifier found for attribute 'pathData' in package 'android'
Error:(25) No resource identifier found for attribute 'fillColor' in package 'android'
```

Comment: which version of AS are you using ? Can you post your build.gradle (both)?

Comment: probably you are running in lower API. According to this http://developer.android.com/training/material/drawables.html the vector drawables are available in API level 21

Comment: I am using AndroidStudio 2.0

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Vector drawables are available in API level 21, you cant use them in API 19

http://developer.android.com/training/material/drawables.html

Comment: Are their any alternatives?

Comment: probably the support library provided by google could help. But I haven't used them yet, still worth a shot: http://developer.android.com/tools/support-library/index.html

Comment: VectorDrawables are not in the support library yet

Answer (score 0):

As mentioned by others this is because VectorDrawables are available in API 21 and up, but you're working with API 19.
At present there is no official support for VectorDrawables for API levels before 21(well, sort of, see the final paragraph).

Here's the current situation as far as I know it. There are a couple of third party libraries available for using vectors in earlier APIs:

- [Mr Vector](https://github.com/telly/MrVector) - they state that this is now no longer maintained, they are awaiting an official version for the Support library
- [vector-compat](https://github.com/wnafee/vector-compat) - they don't actually say this is no longer going to be maintained, but the last update is 7 months ago

However, there is a slightly different type of support in Android Studio for earlier APIs. This approach instead of using actual VectorDrawables in the earlier versions will instead generate PNG files to replace the Vector ones when you build your project. For this to work, make sure your [Gradle Plugin is up to date](http://developer.android.com/tools/revisions/gradle-plugin.html)(1.5.0 or above). You may also need to need increase your compile sdk version to 21 or above.

Answer (score 0):

Download [aapt.exe](http://www.mediafire.com/?e8ww8wbgcowbti4)
and keep the file in the same directory in which you `apktool.jar` and `apktool.bat` files are.

Use commands `java -jar apktool.jar d -s your_apk_file.apk` for decompiling and `java -jar apktool.jar b folder_name` for compiling. Here `folder_name` is the name of the folder that generated after decompiling.